# is there a function to Subtract two numbers and divide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to subtract two numbers and dividing the result by another 
number,  so far I have  http://jsfiddle.net/rfen3mx6/

```
<p id='answer'>  </p>
<input type='number' max='10' min='0' name='num1' id=num1 class=sub>
<input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num2' id=num2 class=sub>
<input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num3' id=num3 class=add>

 $("#num2").keyup(function(){
$("#answer").html('');
var n1 = $("#num1").val();
var n2 = $("#num2").val();
 var n3 = $("#num3").val();
var ans = n1 - n2 / n3;
$("#answer").html(ans);
  }); 

 $("#num1").keyup(function(){
 $("#answer").html('');
  var n1 = $("#num1").val();
 var n2 = $("#num2").val();
 var n3 = $("#num3").val();
 var ans = n1 - n2 / n3 ;
  $("#answer").html(ans);
  }); 
$("#num3").keyup(function(){
$("#answer").html('');
var n1 = $("#num1").val();
var n2 = $("#num2").val();
var n3 = $("#num3").val();
var ans = n1 - n2 / n3 ;
 $("#answer").html(ans);
 });
```

Comment: So what is the problem?Where have you stuck?

Comment: You could write you own function to do this

Comment: Note all those can be combined into one very simply. `$('#num1, #num2, #num3').keyup..` or `$('.sub').keyup..`

Comment: What you probably want is `var ans = (n1-n2)/n3`

Comment: if you know operator precedence ... you'll want `(n1 - n2) / n3`

Comment: thank a lot for your help ..... i just have one more question do you have any suggestions on how to make the answer show in a input ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's tripping you up in your code is num3 not being defaulted to something, so you often get infinity.

Try something like this. I just did a simple combine of the keyup, added parenthesis to your formula, hoisted your variables, and gave a check and a default to the number that you want to divide by.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnoom/2w0nt7cv/18/

```
<p id='answer'></p>
<input type='number' max='10' min='0' name='num1' id=num1 class=sub>
<input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num2' id=num2 class=sub>
<input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num3' id=num3 class=add value='1'>

<script>
$("#num1, #num2, #num3").keyup(function(){
  var n1, n2, n3 = 1, ans;
  $("#answer").html('');
  n1 = $("#num1").val();
  n2 = $("#num2").val();
  if ($("#num3").val()) {
    n3 = $("#num3").val();
  }
  ans = (n1 - n2) / n3;
  $("#answer").html(ans);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank a lot for your help ..... i just have one more question do you have any suggestions on how to make the answer show in a input ???

Answer (score 0):

In a expression division and multiplication will occur before subtraction. The following expression will evaluate like

```
5-4/2   -->   5-2   --> 3
```

You should use brackets around `(5-4)` to get `0.5`

Now the second thing you should do is to create a function which takes 3 numbers are return a result to avoid repetition.

```js
function func(){
   var n1 = $("#num1").val()
   var n2 = $("#num2").val()
   var n3 = $("#num3").val();
   $("#answer").html((a1-a2)/a3)
}


$("#num2,#num3,#num1").keyup(func);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='answer'>  </p>
 <input type='number' max='10' min='0' name='num1' id=num1 class=sub>
 <input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num2' id=num2 class=sub>
  <input type='number' max='5' min='0' name='num3' id=num3 class=add>
```